# C#/SQL Server object history

Tags: c#, sql-server

In a C#/SQL Server application, I want to save object histories:

My Version 1 data looks like this:

> PO: ID=1, name="PO", deliveryDate="1/1/2019"
>   Item 1: ID=1, name="Thing 1", cost=12.95
>   Item 2: ID=2, name="Thing 2", cost=16.59

After a user saves edits to the PO and items, Version 2 looks like this:

> PO: ID=1, name="PO Magnifique", deliverDate="1/2/2019"
>   - Item 1: ID=1, name="Thing 1A", cost=12.95
>   - Item 2: ID=2, name="Thing 2Z", cost=7 
>   - Item 3: ID=3, name="Unexpected Thing", cost=1000

After the user saves Version 2, I want to have access to both the Version 1 data and the Version 2 data.

Before I reinvent the wheel, I'm wondering if somebody has already solved a version of this problem. Maybe a design pattern I'm not familiar with, or a framework, or something I haven't thought of yet. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: Google for "Change Data Capture". It's a feature built into Sql Server Enterprise Edition since 2008 R2, and Standard Edition since 2016 sp1.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like that feature stores changes, and I could theoretically back them out to get the state of a table at a moment in time.

Do you know of a way to avoid the backtracking, and store the state of a row in a table at a point in time?

As I write this, I realize I'm trying to implement version control (a la Git) for objects in my database. Do you have any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 0):

Our client application has a form designer-type view where users can create forms, place controls on them, post new form versions, and deploy posted forms.  The forms are stored as rows in a database with a varied child table structure representing the controls on these forms.

We chose to add form version number column, an integer, to our form table. 
 The form version number is 0 for the "working" version, i.e. all changes are made to this version.  The form data is copied to a new row with the next available version number when a user posts the form to make a new version of it.  For example:

```
create table VersionedTable
(
    RowId bigint identity(1,1) primary key clustered,
    VersionNo int not null check (VersionNo >= 0),
    ...
)
```

If you are looking for a tree of versions, you might opt to have a parent key on each row.  A NULL parent key might represent the root node of the tree.  Rows with no child rows are leaves.

```
create table Node
(
    Id bigint identity(1,1) primary key clustered,
    ParentId bigint NULL,
    ...
)
```